# All positions of the array are modified to the same value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm newbie programming in JavaScript and I have some problems with an array:
When I do a data exchange between an array and another position to position in a loop, all the positions of the array are converted to the same value. That is, the array positions are the same as the last added object.
I leave the code to help me to know what is happening:

```
.controller("UserAndEditLanguagePanel", function (usersFactory, userLanguagesFactory, LanguageFactory) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.userSesion = {};
        var objAux = {};
        objAux.langname = "";
        objAux.level = "";
        vm.lenguajesUsuario = new Array();

        vm.funciones = {
            cargarPerfil: function () {
                usersFactory.obtenerUsuarioSesion().then(function (respuesta) {
                    vm.userSesion.idu = respuesta.idu;
                    vm.userSesion.username = respuesta.username;
                    vm.userSesion.email = respuesta.email;

                    console.log("Se han obtenido los datos de usuario de la sesión correctamente. Respuesta: ", respuesta);
                    userLanguagesFactory.obtenerLenguagesUsuarios().then(function (lenguajesUsuarios) {
                        console.log("Se han obtenidos los datos de los lenguajes de los usuarios. Respuesta: ", lenguajesUsuarios);
                        LanguageFactory.obtenerLenguajes().then(function (listaLenguajes) {
                            console.log("Se han traido los datos de los lenguajes. Respuesta: ", listaLenguajes);
                            console.log(lenguajesUsuarios);


                            for (var i = 0; i < lenguajesUsuarios.length; i++) {
                                if (lenguajesUsuarios[i].idu == vm.userSesion.idu) {
                                    objAux.langname = listaLenguajes[lenguajesUsuarios[i].idl].langname;
                                    objAux.level = lenguajesUsuarios[i].level;
                                    vm.lenguajesUsuario.push(objAux);
                                }
                            }
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Sorry, Sorry, the problem is located in the loop, related to the array "lenguajesUsuarios" and the object "objAux".

Comment: you can delete this question if you found solution within 2 minutes of adding it without anybody's help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Need to initialise the object of objAux inside for loop and and dont crete and initialise the same object before the for loop it will work and fine. 
 .controller("UserAndEditLanguagePanel", function (usersFactory, userLanguagesFactory, LanguageFactory) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.userSesion = {};
        //comment to below object creation and initialisation of object "objAux "
        /*var objAux = {};
        objAux.langname = "";
        objAux.level = "";*/
        vm.lenguajesUsuario = new Array();

        vm.funciones = {
            cargarPerfil: function () {
                usersFactory.obtenerUsuarioSesion().then(function (respuesta) {
                    vm.userSesion.idu = respuesta.idu;
                    vm.userSesion.username = respuesta.username;
                    vm.userSesion.email = respuesta.email;

                    console.log("Se han obtenido los datos de usuario de la sesión correctamente. Respuesta: ", respuesta);
                    userLanguagesFactory.obtenerLenguagesUsuarios().then(function (lenguajesUsuarios) {
                        console.log("Se han obtenidos los datos de los lenguajes de los usuarios. Respuesta: ", lenguajesUsuarios);
                        LanguageFactory.obtenerLenguajes().then(function (listaLenguajes) {
                            console.log("Se han traido los datos de los lenguajes. Respuesta: ", listaLenguajes);
                            console.log(lenguajesUsuarios);


                            for (var i = 0; i < lenguajesUsuarios.length; i++) {
                                if (lenguajesUsuarios[i].idu == vm.userSesion.idu) {
                                    var objAux = {
                                        langname:'',
                                        level:''
                                    }
                                    objAux.langname = listaLenguajes[lenguajesUsuarios[i].idl].langname;
                                    objAux.level = lenguajesUsuarios[i].level;
                                    vm.lenguajesUsuario.push(objAux);
                                }
                            }
```